# Json Serialize Class with Pandas Dataframe Property: TypeError: Object of type 'DataFrame' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, dataframe, serialization

HI I have a class with a pandas dataframe property. How do I encode to json so that the pandas dataframe property gets properly serialized too ?

```
class MachineObject(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):       
        self._MachineName = ''
        self._propsDataFrame = None # Pandas dataframe
```

I am serializing like so:

```
print(json.dumps(machine_objects[0].__dict__))
```

but that is giving me errors:

```
TypeError: Object of type 'DataFrame' is not JSON serializable
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You will have to convert your dataframe to a dictionary.
Instead of
`self._propsDataFrame = df`
do
`self._propsDataFrame = df.to_dict()`

dictionaries are JSON serializable, so you shouldn't get that error anymore.